# Command button not showing underline shortcut in c# client app

Tags: c#, windows, button, client, shortcut

Any ideas what this might be?
See screenshot.
The designer assigns the command button text property to &Copy
.

At design time, you see the underline.
At runtime you don't.
[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT9nH.jpg)

Not a duplicate question.  This problem pertains to solution specific to windows 10.

Comment: @peeyush singh That is not his question about. He knows how to do it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on an older version of Windows this feature is built-in and automatic, but later versions — such as Windows 10 — do not have this feature turned on by default. That is why you can not see this underlined letter.

To enable this feature in Windows 10, open the **Ease of Access Center** and select the link that says **Make the keyboard easier to use**. On the next screen, scroll down to the sub-heading **Make it easier to use keyboard shortcuts** and then click the checkbox labeled **Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys.** [source](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-keyboard-shortcut-alt-underline-3976923)

Answer (score 1):

@Hazz_Rush showed how to change the default visibility.

You can also do this per interaction.  As stated, the default on Windows 10 is to not show the underline.  If you tap the 'Alt' key when the window is in focus then any available controls will switch to display the underline, and can then be triggered by hitting the appropriate key.